# How do I restore the docking guides in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, ux

I lost my docking guides quite some time ago and I can't figure out how to get them back.

Initially, I thought maybe it was an OS (Windows 7) configuration but my visual studio docking guides work correctly.

I can still dock, but it's the old style of docking (no docking guides).

ArcGIS 10 SP2 in Windows 7, x64

[image: Viewing Multiple Tables]

Comment: Can you clarify what a docking guide is? The little 4 arrow graphic that lets you decide where to snap the window to?

Comment: That's correct. The 4 arrow graphic with the "tab' option in the center. *It was the only good thing about ArcGIS 10 (just kidding...but it is one of my favorite things about ArcGIS 10).*

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the little pushpin in the auto-hide mode? I assume you've tried a restart and repair ArcMap installation already.

Comment: Restart: Yes. Repair: No  I have no reason to assume anything is broken, just that I don't know how to get it back (which is why I posted the question).  ArcCatalog does show the docking guides.

Comment: Since normally holding the ctrl key down while dragging causes the guides to disappear, I wonder what would happen if you did this on a machine where the guides are not visible to begin with.

Comment: Holding down the ctrl behaves as it did back in 9.3 and prevents docking from occurring (keep in mind, I could still dock...just no guides so you end up guessing as to where the window was going to end up).  I'm all fixed now, although I slipped up during troubleshooting, so I only know the culprit was in the `HKCU\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap` somewhere...just not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the `HKCU\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap` key and restarted ArcMap. Docking guides are back!

I'm not sure what the precise setting is since I accidentally deleted my original `ArcMap` key during troubleshooting. But it wasn't DockingPaneLayouts (which was the first one I tried).

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out!